# Edit File in bash script by sed command

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I am a beginner in bash script, and I am facing a problem.
I created file "script.sh" and I want to open template file and replace specific attributes with different values. Here is my script and I appreciate if someone tell me what is the problem ..

```
#!/bin/bash
TEMPLATEFILE="Template.xml"
XMLDir="Results"
OUTPUTDir="Output"
TIMES=2 
QUAN=50
DIST=150
OUTPUT_File="Output_"
mkdir  $XMLDir      
mkdir  $OUTPUTDir   
rm -rf $XMLDir      
rm -rf $OUTPUTDir   
echo $TIMES
x=1
echo ${x}
while [ $x -le $TIMES ]
do
    RANDOMVAR =${Random}
    outputFile=${OUTPUT_File}"_"${QUAN}"_"${RANDOMVAR}"_"${DIST}".xml"
    outputText=${OUTPUT_File}"_"${QUAN}"_"${RANDOMVAR}"_"${DIST}".txt"
    touch ${outputFile}  
        sed -e "s/$SEEDVALUE/$RANDOMVAR/"
            -e "s/$EXPIREMENT/$QUAN/"
            -e "s/$DISTANCE/$DIST/"
            -e "s/$OUTPUTFILE/$outputText/"
            < $TEMPLATEFILE > $outputFile
    echo $outputFile" is generated in "$x" iteration out of "$TIMES
    x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
echo "done"
```

I run the file in terminal by : bash script.sh

The xml file contains a lot of lines, but I am trying to change the following:

```
<run length="0" seed_value="SEEDVALUE" />
<outputfileName name="expirement" output="OUTPUTFILE" />
<distancevalue value="DISTANCE" />
<entity number="EXPIREMENT" base_num="1">
```

When running the script , it gives me "unexpected end of file"

Comment: Remove the space after the variable name in the assignment: `RANDOMVAR=`. Otherwise, shell tries to run the command `RANDOMVAR` with `=` as the argument.

Comment: Thanks, I did but still have same problem

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you show the complete code?

Comment: Yes, both files xml and bash script are complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed -e "s/$SEEDVALUE/$RANDOMVAR/"

This command is taking a variable "$SEEDVALUE" and replacing it with "$RANDOMVAR" but you are never setting the SEEDVALUE to anything. The actual command that you are issuing looks like this:

sed -e "s//$RANDOMVAR/"

For my string replace placeholders I usually make them stand out by using "handlebars" {{ }}.

Try this instead:

First make sure that your template file contains the placeholder {{SEEDVALUE}}. Second, you do not need to do the first redirect "<" sed will act on a file if you simply pass it in.

Here is a VERY simplified version to help make things clearer:

```
echo "This is some line. This is what was replaced with my placeholder: {{SEEDVALUE}}" > /tmp/testfile

RANDOMVAR="my new text"

sed -e "s/{{SEEDVALUE}}/$RANDOMVAR/" /tmp/testfile > /tmp/testfile-replaced

cat /tmp/testfile-replaced
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like those sed commands arguments are not on the same line and line shift is not escaped. Try:

```
sed -e "s/$SEEDVALUE/$RANDOMVAR/" \
    -e "s/$EXPIREMENT/$QUAN/" \
    -e "s/$DISTANCE/$DIST/" \
    -e "s/$OUTPUTFILE/$outputText/" \
    < $TEMPLATEFILE > $outputFile
```

Also, to get more debugging information, it's often useful to use the following as interpreter:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

Comment: I tried also only one sed -e "s/$SEEDVALUE/$RANDOMVAR/" only, but never work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing.
I don't think $SEEDVALUE variable is defined.

I think your sed command should start a bit more like this

```
sed -e "s/seed_value=\"[0-9]*\"/seed_value=\"$RANDOMVAR\"/g"
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't work , can you write a complete line of sed command?